# MDX: how to get dimension values as columns

Tags: mdx

firstly i apologize because i'm most certainly using the wrong terms here. My problem is that i have the query below that contains a dimension that has always two values (MONTH VALIDATION) as shown on the query and image below:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[00 - Costs €] 
}
ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {(
    [Project Platoon].[Platoon].[Platoon].ALLMEMBERS ,
    [Financial Data Month Validation].[Month Validation Status].[Month Validation Status].ALLMEMBERS
)} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
    FROM 
        [DataCube] 
        CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

and i get a result like the one below:

[image]

My question is: how can i "flatify" this so that i show

|Platoon|Open |Closed|Costs|

|Borg...|12.000|99.000|12+99=111|

that is, transform the values of [MonthValidation] into columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `Month Validation Status` hierarchy on the columns (that is why there is `ON COLUMNS` and `ON ROWS`):

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    [Measures].[00 - Costs €] 
} *
[Financial Data Month Validation].[Month Validation Status].[Month Validation Status].ALLMEMBERS
ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY {
    [Project Platoon].[Platoon].[Platoon].ALLMEMBERS 
} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
    FROM 
        [DataCube] 
        CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```