# SSAS 2008 R2: How to create dataset fields manually

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mdx, ssas-2008

So, this is a follow up question to  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938229/mdx-how-to-get-dimension-values-as-columns) i made before.

Basically, i wanted to go from

[image]

to

[image]

which i got.

My final problem is that i dont seem to be able to create a name for these fields for the datasets in ssas.

I tried:

```
FIELD NAME=CLOSED,  FIELD SOURCE=

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Level" UniqueName="[Financial Data Month Validation].[Month Validation Status].[Month Validation Status].ALLMEMBERS" />
```

I tried ALLMEMBERS, CLOSED, OPEN and some other variations. I m new to this but i have been able to manually create fields before. I think its the two header columns crating my problem here. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to change the column headers? If so, what do you want to see on the column headers? Just the Month validation status?

Comment: is not change. Is add a name so i can reference them anywhere else in a report. i cant seem to find a valid expression for the names

Comment: What is the interface you are using to call the report?